# Generate X.509 certificate in java program without using sun.security or bouncycastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509certificate, x509certificate2, jce

I would like to know an approach to create X.509 certificates in java without using "sun.security.x509.*" package and bouncycastle dependency.

Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Just copy the bouncycastle code, obeying the license requirements therein which are very liberal as I recall. It's unclear what kind of answer you're expecting.

Comment: I am not supposed to use bouncycastle dependency in my project nor the "sun.security" packages are they are deprecated. I would like to know is it possible in java 8 to create certificates without dependencies to "sun.security" package or bouncycstle. Just heard about unlimited key strength JCE, can it be used to create and sign certificates

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: The 'unlimited strength' _policy for_ JCE (which never was the JCE itself) is obsolete; 8u151 up and java 9 and 10 no longer use it. In the past, it affected only symmetric encryption and had no relationship with or effect on certificates at all. Standard JCE API and providers can use _existing_ certs (to verify signatures etc) but not create them. If you want no dependency, you must either write the code or copy it from somewhere, of which BC is a good choice but there might be others.